# How do we prevent clicking a button again and again for a specific time in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, debugging, animation

So in the code, pressing the button will animate the red box.
Clicking the button will diagonally move it.
but if we click the button again while the animation is happening or clicking it multiple times gives a flickering effect.
How do we fix this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
#container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
}
#animate {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
}
</style>
<body>

<p><button onclick="myMove()">Click Me</button></p> 

<div id ="container">
  <div id ="animate"></div>
</div>

<script>
function myMove() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("animate");   
  var pos = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 5);
  function frame() {
    if (pos == 350) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      pos++; 
      elem.style.top = pos + "px"; 
      elem.style.left = pos + "px"; 
    }
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set a flag when the animation is in progress and don't execute the function when it's still in progress

```js
var animationInProgress = false;

function myMove() {
  if (animationInProgress) {
    return;
  }

  var elem = document.getElementById("animate");
  var pos = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 5);
  animationInProgress = true;

  function frame() {
    if (pos == 350) {
      animationInProgress = false;
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      pos++;
      elem.style.top = pos + "px";
      elem.style.left = pos + "px";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
}

#animate {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<p><button onclick="myMove()">Click Me</button></p>

<div id="container">
  <div id="animate"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: May I also add that it's much preferable to handle the animation by using CSS transition instead of vanilla JS animation - much smoother, and can be handled by GPU instead of CPU, thus improving the web app performance.

Comment: I was going to suggest a timer but this is a much better solution. Also prefer CSS animations.

Comment: yes @Artanis . I strongly recommend CSS animation over JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways I can think of:

The first is to disable the button, and create a timer (setTimeout) to re-enable it

The second is to save the time of the second click, and check in your click handler if another click happens too soon (using the saved 2nd click time).